# Vertx: unexpected verticle behaviour, endpoint triggering twice

Tags: vert.x

I have written a simple vertx applicatino:

```
public class MyFirstVerticle extends AbstractVerticle {

    private int counter = 0;

    @Override
    public void start() {
        vertx.createHttpServer()
                .requestHandler(req -> {
                    ++counter;
                    req.response().end("Hi from "
                            + Thread.currentThread().getName() + ",called "+counter+ " times");
                })
                .listen(8080);
    }
}
```

So for every request I am incrementing counter by one,and then returning a message with thread name and value of counter.

I send the request from browser one by one. So I expect counter to show up as 1,2,3,4 and so on.

But what I observe is that counter values are increasing randomly...1,3,4,6,10,11,13..something like this.

I am not able to understand this behaviour.

Comment: How are you deploying the Verticle?

Comment: I just run command: mvn compile vertx:run

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're listening to all types of requests. That includes `favicon.ico` requests, that come from your browser. If you would run the requests using `curl`, you shouldn't see that behaviour anymore.